# PHP Variables from different .php file do not synchronize (Variable Scope issue)

Tags: php, jquery

I have 1 html, 1 javascript file and 3 php files, purposed as below:

script.js : used to pass user-entered variables from html to calculate.php without refreshing the html page. then get the result from calculate.php and pass it to certain div in my html.

calculate.php : include parameters.php and functions.php,  after that, do the calculation.

```
    <?php 
    include 'parameters.php'; 
    include 'functions.php';
    call_user_func("do_something()");
    ?>
```

parameters.php: where I define variables.

```
<?php
$var = $_POST['data_from_js']
?>
```

functions.php: where I define functions and their "if" conditions, and these "if" conditions uses variables defined in parameters.php

```
<?php
function do_something()
{
if ($var == 100)
    {
     echo 200;
    }
}
?>
```

everything works fine, except that when calculate.php called the user function "do_something", the "if" condition doesn't work, because the $var is always 0

and if I move the "if" condition from functions.php to calculate.php, like below:

functions.php:

```
<?php
function do_something()
{
echo 200;
}
?>
```

Calculate.php:

```
<?php
include 'parameters.php'; 
include 'functions.php';

if($var == 100)
{
 call_user_func("do_something()");
}
?>
```

Then it works, the value of $var is just exactly what user entered in the html, and it returns 200 into somewhere in the html if the user enters 100 in the field.

so, variables defined in parameters.php,
can be read and get the value (by $_post method) inside calculate.php, where my javascript sends data to.

But it cannot be read inside the function which I defined in functions.php, 
when included and called by calculate.php.

It confuses me a little bit, I guess it's something about synchronization, and how php works on its sequence...

my question is:
Is there a simple way I can make it work without moving the "if" condition from functions.php to calculate.php, or make my javascript send data directly into functions.php?

The reason I'd like to do this is to keep the code organized, categorized and explicit so I can know what to modify if needed. The real calculation.php is actually a little bit complicated that I want to separate functions from it.

It's my first post here so if there's something confusing please let me know, thank you guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with the variable scope. Check this article from the official PHP site: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Try using `global $val;` at the beginning of the `do_something()` function, so the function *knows* that `$var` is a global version of the variable, instead of the local one to the function:

```
<?php
function do_something()
{
    global $var;

    if ($var == 100)
    {
        echo 200;
    }
}
?>
```

Alternatively, and as suggested by other user, you may want to pass the value as a parameter to the function, and avoid the use of global variables (and their potential issues).

Comment: Thank you, it works now!  I have only some knowledge about variable scope...I am aware that I have to declare a variable as global inside a function if I want to use it outside the function, but didn't know that I have to declare a variable defined in other .php file inside a function as global if I want to use it inside the function. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass the variable

```
$var = $_POST['data_from_js'];

do_something($var);

function do_something($var){
...
```

Comment: Thank you, in this example it works, but somehow I need to do it in other way (define $var as global) in my real code...still appreciate for your answer!